# Boundedness and openness of the set

Tags: functional-analysis

> Need to prove/disprove boundedness and openness of the set $S=\left\{f\in L_1[1,\infty):\;\displaystyle\int\limits_1^\infty x|f(x)|dx<1\right\}$.

There are no problems with boundedness. But I can’t check the openness. If $f_0\in S$ and $f\in B_r(f_0)$, then $\displaystyle\int\limits_1^\infty x|f_0(x)|dx<1$ and $\displaystyle\int\limits_1^\infty |f(x)-f_0(x)|dx<r$. But then $\displaystyle\int\limits_1^\infty x|f(x)|dx\leq \displaystyle\int\limits_1^\infty x|f(x)-f_0(x)|dx+\displaystyle\int\limits_1^\infty x|f_0(x)|dx$ and i can't see how to use that $f\in B_r(f_0)$. For the same reason, it is not possible to verify that the mapping $\varphi(f)=\displaystyle\int\limits_1^\infty x|f(x)|dx$ is continuous, since everything spoils the factor $x$. Maybe, need to disprove the openness, but i also don't know how. Can anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, we find that the set fails to be open.  To see that this is the case, consider the sequence $f_n$ defined by
$$
f_n(x) = \frac 1{n+1} \mathbf 1_{[n,n+2]}.
$$
We see that $\int_1^\infty x|f_n(x)|dx=2$ for $n = 1,2,3,\dots$ and that $f_n \to 0 \in S$. So, we conclude that the complement of $S$ fails to be closed, which means that $S$ fails to be open.

Comment: Very nice, thank you!